# Trimming value from database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$quiztotal = mysql_query('SELECT id,username,qname,quizpercentage FROM quiz');

echo '<table><tr><th>USERNAME</th>
                 <th>QUIZ NAME</th>
                 <th>PERCENTAGE</th>
                 <th>GRADE</th>
                 <th>POINTS</th></tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($quiztotal))
{
    $username = $row['username'];
    $qtotal = $row['quizpercentage'];
    $defaultsetting = mysql_query('SELECT id,letter,percentage,points FROM default');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($defaultsetting))
    {
        $letter = $row['letter'];
        $percentage = $row['percentage'];
        $points = $row['points'];
        echo '<tr><td>'.$username.'</td>
                  <td>'.qtotal.'</td>';
                  echo 'td>';
                    if(qtotal == $percentage)
                    {
                      echo $letter;
                    }
                  echo '</td>';
                  echo '<td>';
                  if($letter)
                  {
                     echo $points;
                  }
                  echo '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Quiz Table

```
id    username   quizpercentage
1        35          66%
2        47          78%
3        53          90%     
4        56          96%
5        4           45%
```

default Table

```
   id     letter   percentage     points
   1        A         >=85         4.00
   2        B         80-84        3.67
   3        C         83-75        2.65
   4        D         74-55        2.00
```

Here >=85 is nothing starts from 85% to 100% and
80-84 is 80%,81% and 84% 
How can I match correctly like suppose if user scores 88%, how could I give a grade for each user and if grade is A/B/C/D i should show points too
I need the output like

```
  USERNAME      QUIZ NAME         PERCENTAGE      GRADE   POINTS
   35           TestSeries          85%            A       4.00
   47           TestSeries          70%            C       2.65
   53           preliminary         62%            D       2.00
```

Comment: Please **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` in new applications. This is a legacy interface from the 1990s that is in the process of being retired, and it's also very dangerous when used incorrectly, possibly leading to severe SQL injection bugs that could be exploited. It's best to use either `mysqli` or PDO in new projects. [Several examples](http://bobby-tables.com/php) show how it isn't that much different from what you're doing here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it easily with the table structures you have right now, you'll need some changes. First one would be changing `Quiz` table so that field `QuizPercentage` contains a number (without the "%" sign). This should be done anyway because formatting belongs to the web page, not the database.

Next step would be adding two columns to table `default` (is that really the name? If yes, it's not a good name either). The two new columns would be the following:
- `PercentageFrom int`
- `PercentageTo int`

They will contain, respectively, the minimum and the maximum value of each score range. That means your table will look something like this:

```
  id     letter   percentage     points  PercentageFrom  PercentageTo
   1        A         >=85         4.00        85           100
   2        B         80-84        3.67        84            84
   3        C         83-75        2.65        75            83
   4        D         74-55        2.00        55            74
```

Now you would simply have to join `Quiz` table with the `Scores` table and get the data you need.

```
SELECT
  Q.id
  ,Q.username
  ,Q.qname
  ,Q.quizpercentage
  ,S.Letter
  ,S.Points
FROM
  Quiz Q
  JOIN
  Scores S ON
    (Q.quizpercentage BETWEEN S.PercentageFrom AND PercentageTo)
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, cannot we take the row value as >=85 or 80-84 and trim he data in php. Is there any other way rather than this b'coz the dafault table is looks like that

Comment: This is a nice solution, although it seems like there should be a way to avoid the redundancy of having both PercentageFrom and PercentageTo, since PercentageFrom will always be 1+ PercentageTo of the next lower grade.

Comment: @karthik You could do that, but why would you want to when you can do it directly in the DB?

Comment: Barmer@ Actually we have the table in DB like that in MOODLE, so we can't change the settings or else I would have done by adding two columns from and to.

Comment: Hi Diego, Is my query correct and is the correct way of checking

Comment: @Barmar There isn't a way to easily "figure out" the end of a range using pure SQL, because the information you'd need would be in another row. That would mean using loops, like "for each row->read next row->get its value minus one". It would be far easier to manage ranges (which are usually rarely modified) during input. Personal experience.

Comment: How about `select q.id, q.percentage, min(s.letter) grade from quiz q, join scores s on q.percentage >= s.minpercentage`? However, I agree that this isn't as efficient, and you need another join to get additional columns from the scores table.

Comment: @Barmar That query assumes that letters will be ordered in descending order, while I saw systems using also "S" as "more than A" (rare, but it exists) or intermediate scores, such as B+ and so on. In my experience, it's good not to assume anything and rely on solid data instead. Besides, OP also needs the points, which are ordered the other way round.

Comment: OK, you could use `max(s.percentage)` instead, and then another join to get the grade, points, etc.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure that will work either, since `percentage` contains values such as `>=85`. I'm pretty sure they are formatted strings, which are not the best candidates for this kind of operations.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `max(s.minpercentage)`, which replaces `s.percentagefrom`.

Answer (score 2):

your default is readable only by humans, it should look like this:

```
id     letter   percentage_from percentage_to     points
1        A         85           100               4.00
2        B         80           84                3.67
3        C         75           79                2.65
4        D         55           74                2.00 
5        E         0            54                2.00
```

Then your query can be something like :

```
$quiztotal 
= mysql_query(
'SELECT quiz.id, quiz.username,quiz.qname, default.letter, default.points
 FROM quiz, default 
 where quiz.quizpercentage <= defaut.percentage_to
 and quiz.quizpercentage  >= defaut.percentage_from');
```

and you'd have all the information you want

Comment: Answer is fairly good, but I recommend not to suggest using natural joins.

Comment: thanks for the precision, my answer is mainly focused on the table structurer though

Answer (score 0):

Check out `CASE` syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: That's not a good idea, as it would imply hardcoding the values and the output. The right way of doing it would be restructuring the database.